# set height to 0 for header view of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I used the code below to set the height of header view of UITableView

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0; //  

    return height;
}
```

but it display abnormal, shown as below

[image]

there is a white block, your comment welcome

Comment: please include datasource methods used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return `nil` from your implementation of `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
//return header view for specified section of table view
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //check header height is valid
    if([self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section] == 0.0)
    {
        //bail
        return nil;
    }

    //create header view
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section])];

    //

    //return header view
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

The Tableview frame is not set properly.check in code or nib

The delegate return the headerview height and it is proper in the Table since there is no space between the edge of tableview and cell

use `setFrame` method to properly set via code

Setting height to 0 will not change section height of grouped table.So as a tweak use a very smaller value but not 0 like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat height = 0.001;   
    return height;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of that header view that shows up this does it.  This allows for re-use of a grouped as a plain UITableView without that header view popping up at the top. -- Thx @Lithu T.V.

Comment: It works but need to override heightForFooterInSection method also!

Answer (score 10):

**swift 4**

As other answers said, if you return 0 for height, it is means you say set default.

use small number like `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude` to solve problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

0 means default.
Make the height extremely small such as 0.01 to "hide" it.

Comment: Apple has a lot of such obscure hacks. Another example which is more known is when you set a UILabel's `numberOfLines` to `0`. You'd normally expect that `0` means zero lines, yet it means flexible number of lines!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting header height to 0.001 didn’t work. Still, there was some space showing. So, I had to do this-

```
tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
```

Since iOS 15, UITableView contains a new property called **sectionHeaderTopPadding** which specifies the amount of padding above each section header.